# Convert this Select into CakePHP-friendly Select

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp-2.2

I have the following model relationships

```
Post belongsto PostCategory
PostCategory belongsto Forum
PostSubcat belongsto PostCategory

PostCategory hasmany Post
PostCategory hasmany PostSubcat
Forum hasmany PostCategory.
```

I'm working on my ForumsController add() method and I couldn't use the standard find('list') to display all the forums, categories and subcategories a user can add a post to. For example the drop down should look like...

```
- Forum #1 Title
    - Category #1.1 Title
        - Subcat #1.1 Title
        - Subcat #1.2 Title
    - Category #1.2 Title
    - Category #1.3 Title
        - Subcat #2.1 Title
        - Subcat #2.2 Title
- Forum #2 Title
    - Category #2.1 Title
    - Category #2.2 Title
```

So instead I did a find('all') like so...

```
$forums = $this->Forum->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Forum.title'),
    'conditions' => array('Forum.page_id' => $page_id),
    'contain' => array(
        'PostCategory' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'PostCategory.id', 'PostCategory.title'
            ),
            'PostSubcat' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'PostSubcat.id', 'PostSubcat.title'
                ),
            )
        )
    )
));

$this->set('forums', $forums);
```

My add.ctp forum has the following code for the select

```
<?php if($forums): ?>
    <div class="input select required"><label for="PostCategoryId">Category</label>
    <select name="data[Post][category_id]" id="PostCategoryId">
        <option value="">Select a Category</option>
        <?php foreach($forums as $forum): ?>
            <?php if(!empty($forum['PostCategory'])): ?>
                <option value="" class="SelectSeparator"><?php echo $forum['Forum']['title']; ?></option>
                <?php foreach($forum['PostCategory'] as $category): ?>
                   <?php if($category_id == $category['id']){
                       $selected = "selected";
                   }else{
                       $selected = "not";
                   } ?>
                   <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $category['title']; ?></option>
                   <?php foreach($category['PostSubcat'] as $subcat): ?>
                       <?php if($category_id == $subcat['id']){
                           $selected = "selected";
                       }else{
                           $selected = "not";
                       } ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $subcat['id']; ?>"<?php echo $selected;?>>-- <?php echo $subcat['title']; ?></option>
                   <?php endforeach; // subcat?>
               <?php endforeach; // category ?>
           <?php endif; // if forum has categories ?>
       <?php endforeach; // forum?>
   </select> 
   </div>
<?php endif; // if there are forums ?>
```

This displays the select options exactly how I want it to and it validates correctly--it won't add the post if a user selects a forum title or selects "Select a Category" instead of a category title. However, it is not in a Cake-friendly format so that validation errors do not display.

Is there a way to easily convert this to a CakePHP Form->input helper so that the validation error message can display properly?

Comment: Logistical question: when you want to add the forum/category/subcategory in the add function, how do you recognize which is which if you only have the id? (I know it doesn't have to do with your problem, but I'm curious about how you're handling this).

Comment: well category and subcategory are from the same table posts_category. That table has a column called parent_id if you are adding something to a sub category you would be able to get it's parent. It also has another column called filter_id, in the case of my ForumsController the filter_id is the foreign key for the table forums. I have other controllers where the filer_id would relate to something else so filter_id just sounded like a good neutral name.

Comment: Do you have a validation for category_id in your Post model?

Comment: yes my post model has a numeric rule for category_id but allowed empty is true and required is false. therefore category_id can be blank but if it is filled out then it must be numeric. but in my forums controller, i unset the validation rules for category_id and set it exactly how i have it above. the validation works, just no error messages are displayed. if i use the standard find('list') and this->Form->input('category_id') then the validation messages are displayed